# Angular Pipe for search field

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5, angular-pipe

I have a pipe which filters the search field, and displays the list of items according to search text. Currently, it filters only companyDisplay. Goal is to filter companyCode and companyDisplay

JSON

```
[{
    companyDisplay: "ABC",
    companyName: "EFG",
    companyCode: "1234"
}]
```

Search Pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core'; // serach text sorting
@Pipe({
    name: 'searchCompanyPipe'
})
export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any[], searchText: any): any[] {
    if (!items) { return []; }
    if (!searchText) { return items; }
    searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();
    return items.filter(i => {
      return (i.companyDisplay || i.companyCode).toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
    });
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<li *ngFor="let data of companyInfo| searchPipe:searchValue">
```

`companyInfo` holds the json.

Comment: I wrote a blog post on why you should consider *not* using a pipe for filtering along with alternative implementations: https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/filtering-in-angular/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that the following code:

```
(i.companyDisplay || i.companyCode)
```

always returns `companyDisplay` as long as it is not a falsy value. You need to use something like:

```
return i.companyDisplay.toLowerCase().includes(searchText) || i.companyCode.toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
```

Comment: The above code doesn't filter companyDisplay or companyCode. It throws "Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined" error. Any other insights? Thanks.

Comment: It worked.  some objects in json was missing companyCode which returned undefined error. Thanks